# Use of cut to display information from last command linux

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am trying to fetch the user name and IP from where they logged in on my system.

I used the following command:

```
last -i | grep 'Jan 12' | cut -f1,3
```

But I am getting full line as the result.

But when I use awk :

```
last -i | grep 'Jan 12' | awk '{print $1, $3}'
```

I am getting the correct result.

Why wrong output in case of cut command ?

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: @downvoter,  please tell the reason for downvoting so that it can help me in the future.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Default delimiter of `cut` is a tab, whereas default input field separator in `awk` is any whitespace i.e. space or tab.

To get the same behavior in `cut`, you need to add `-d ' '` in `cut` to make it:

```
last -i | grep 'Jan 12' | tr -s ' ' | cut -d ' ' -f1,3
```

`tr -s ' '` is required to squeeze multiple spaces into a single space.

However using `awk` lets you skip `grep` altogether and use:

```
last -i | awk '/Jan 12/{print $1, $3}'
```

Comment: I don't think the `cut` will work. There are multiple spaces between fields produced by `last`. So you might need to do something like `tr -s ' '` before.

Comment: On my ubuntu, `last -i` output doesn't have multiple spaces. But yes if there are multiple spaces then `tr -s ' '` will be needed.

Comment: The cut is not working even after adding -d ' '  due to multiple spaces.

Comment: @BhawandeepSingla: Please see discussion above your comment and updated answer with `tr -s ' '`

Comment: @anubhava, yes I saw that. It is working now. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @anubhava, `awk '/Jan 12/{print $1, $3}'` may not work as you expected, cause there could be multiple spaces between `Jan` and `12`

Comment: I have used `last` command on my OSX and Ubuntu systems and both don't have multiple spaces between month and date. But if that is really the case on your system then use: `last -i | awk '/Jan[[:blank:]]+12/{print $1, $3}'`

Comment: @anubhava, you'll have multiple spaces on `Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS`

Answer (score 0):

In `cut`, default delimiter is `[Tab]`. Also with `-d` key you can specify only a single character as delimiter.
In `last` output there are 8 spaces in a row.

So, the best way is to use `awk` as in your example.

Bad, but working solution with cut:

```
last | grep 'Jun 23' | sed 's/\s\s*/ /g' | cut -d' ' -f1,3
```

Comment: The default is `<tab>` I think.

Comment: @PesaThe True. My bad.